# edited ics file does not set an event on phone calendar automatically

Tags: icalendar

I am trying to edit a file that a transport company sent me which automatically set my trip information in my calendar . I want to edit this file so that it can reminds me other events but, when i change the date and send it to myself or another email adress, it doesn't set the event automatically anymore. What is the problem?

Even sending the same file, not even changing the date, gives the same problem.

i tried to read this guide https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-165 but have not found anything...

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:d0b7191f-b3af-419b-af93-b795f0dde86
PRIORITY:1
DTSTART:20190830T142500
DTEND:20190830T173800
LOCATION:Torino Porta Nuova
DESCRIPTION:Torino Porta Nuova-Albenga;
 Treno: Regionale Veloce 10113, pa
 rtenza da Torino Porta Nuova Ore: 14:25; arrivo a Albenga 

Ore: 17:38
 Codi
 ce Biglietto: 120303025;
 


 
ORGANIZER:CN=ORGANIZER:mailto:webmaster@trenitalia.it
SUMMARY:Viaggio Torino Porta Nuova-Albenga, Treno Regionale 

Veloce 10113, 
 Codice Biglietto 120303025 ,  
 
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=BUYER:mailto:MY_EMAIL_ADRESS_REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CN=TRAVELLER:MY_EMAIL_ADRESS_REMOVED_FOR_PRIVACY
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: How are you embedding the new updated event in your email?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!! the voice "organizer" must be the mail who send the event and you have to write the mail of the receivers to the "attedee" voice (i don't know yet if this is strictly necessary)